# Webpack 4, watch folders outside file structure

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I have an application built and watched with webpack in development mode, in that project I dynamically require modules in folders in other projects that are outside the scope. I'd like to watch these folders and trigger a recompile if they change (or a new file is added). I've found some information and this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filewatcher-webpack-plugin) but nothing seems to work with webpack 4. I'm now down to the code below for my `webpack.dev.js` which I think should work but doesn't recompile on changes.

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        function (compiler) {
            compiler.hooks.afterCompile.tapAsync('WatchDecorators', (compilation, callback) => {
                projectDecoratorPaths.forEach(decoratorFolder => {
                    compilation.contextDependencies.add(decoratorFolder);
                });
                callback();
            });
        }
    ]
});
```

The `projectDecoratorPaths` is an array of folders that look like `projectName/src/js/folder/*.js`. but when I change a file in one of those folders or add a file nothing happens in watch. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Or how else can I get this to work?

EDIT: I've now found [webpack-watch-files-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-watch-files-plugin) which should work with webpack 4 and seems well used and maintained, but even when it confirms it's watching the exact external files it still doesn't recompile on change. I'm not using Hot Module Replacement, code below.

```
plugins: [
    new WatchExternalFilesPlugin({
        files: projectDecoratorPaths,
        verbose: true
    })
]
```